# Show menu item only for logged-on users

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm new to ASP.NET MVC and am using version 1.0 of the framework. I have a site.master page with the following hard-coded menu

```
<div id="menucontainer">
    <ul id="menu">              
    <li><%= Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home")%></li>
    <li><%= Html.ActionLink("Drivers", "List/?category=Drivers", "Product")%></li>
    <li><%= Html.ActionLink("Irons", "List/?category=Irons", "Product") %></li>
    <li><%= Html.ActionLink("Wedges", "List/?category=Wedges", "Product") %></li>
    <li><%= Html.ActionLink("Putters", "List/?category=Putters", "Product") %></li> 
    </ul>  
 </div>
```

I want to show an extra item on the menu only if users are logged on. Something like "View My Listings". I have no problem doing this in a dirty hacky way so I have tried

```
<% if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated) ...
```

but `User` is not valid in this context. My question is how to show an extra menu item only if users are logged on?

Comment: I use HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated in my view to manage menu items.

Comment: What's the difference between using HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated, Context.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated and Request.IsAuthenticated??

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can access the User object through the Context object:

```
<% if(Context.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated) ...
```

Answer (score 10):

I also just discovered that I could use

```
<% if (Request.IsAuthenticated) { %>
  <li><%= Html.ActionLink("View my Listings", "MyListings", "List")%>
<% } %>
```

Comment: works in MVC 5 for me. Just replaced with the Razor syntax (@).

Answer (score 7):

For MVC 4+ We do like this:

```
@if(Context.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated) {
     <li> @Html.ActionLink(... 
   }
```