# Show admin panel button only if user is logged in and is in admin role

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

Basicly my questions is based on this question here:

[Show menu item only for logged-on users](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3268860/show-menu-item-only-for-logged-on-users)

The way they solved it in previouse question is a hacky way. I read a little about this problem, and found out that you have to create custom HTML Helper, which going to show or hide button based on user Role.

So it in View it will looks something like :

```
 @HTML.MyCustomHelperWhichShowButton("ButtonText");
```

But how should I implement such a helper?

Comment: Have you looked at this question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10998827/custom-html-helpers-in-mvc-4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But how should I implement such a helper?

By writing an extension method to the `HtmlHelper` class:

```
public static class HtmlExtensions
{
    public static IHtmlString MyCustomHelperWhichShowButton(this HtmlHelper html, string text)
    {
        var isAuthnticated = html.ViewContext.HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated;
        if (isAuthnticated)
        {
            return html.ActionLink(text, "MyListings", "List");
        }

        return new HtmlString(string.Empty);
    }
}
```

and by adding the namespace in which you defined this class to the `<namespaces>` section of your `~/Views/web.config` file which will bring this helper into scope in all your views.